# How to prevent Datagrid from reusing itemRenderers?

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer

Is it possible to not to reuse the itemrenderers on scroll in a datagrid. Instead on scroll datagrid should create the new instances of the itemrenderers?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want the DataGrid to reuse itemrenderers?

Comment: For all intends and purposes, it should probably not matter much to you that Flex is reusing item renderers as you scroll through the items in a data set.  If you're running into problems, it could be because you need some help understanding what's happening during that process.  Could you explain more the issues you're having?  Then we might be able to help you through them.

Comment: I think the idea of an ItemRenderer is to be reused. So if you really need to recreate all the elements on a collection change, then you might probably have to do that manually and not by using a ListBase component.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't recommended but it looks like you can do this by setting the `useVirtualLayout` param to `false`:

```
<s:List>  
   <s:layout>  
      <s:VerticalLayout useVirtualLayout="false" />  
   <s:/layout>  
</s:list>
```

NB: This is for Flex 4.x